# C++: Create a new object with a reference variable

Tags: c++, vector

In a function I get as an argument the reference to a vector:

```
void myFunc (vector< int>& myRef) {...}
```

Now in this function I need to backup (because myRef will become something else) the reference to that particular vector:

```
vector< int>& myBackup = myRef
```

Now I want myRef to become a reference to a NEW COPY of that vector. How do I do that?

Can I just say

```
vector< int> myRef = myBackup
```

?

Is the result myBackup = a reference to the original object and myRef = a reference to a copy of the original object?

Comment: It would be helpful if you post the actual code here so we can see in what scope you're making these backup/copies.

Answer (score 2):

C++ references cannot be changed to refer to new objects after they are initially assigned. If you need that kind of behavior, you have to use a pointer.

Answer (score 0):

Does this code compile? You should really make use of a pointer here, if you want to reassign, as references can't be reassigned. A simple rule of thumb is if you want to be able to reassign the variable use a pointer, so long as it is advisable to do so in the current situation.

For example:

```
void myFunction(std::vector<int*> myPtr) {}
```

Answer (score 0):

To solve this problem you need to make deep copy
You can use memcpy but it is not a safe way;
or such as

```
vector<int> newVector;
newVector.reserve(myRef.size()); //for performance, to avoid realloc
for (vector< int>::iterator it = myRef.begin();it!=myRef.end();++it)
   newVector.push_back(*it);
myRef = newVector;
```

And after this line

```
vector< int>& myBackup = myRef
```

you have a compiler error with redeclaration of myRef...